# Windows 10 Universal App Key Press Simulation, what OS Context?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm attempting to perform several key presses using [InputSimulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) in Windows Universal App in VS Studio 2015.

These key presses are registered in Win 10 when I have the following line in a Console Application. However, this does not work in a Windows Universal Application.

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
```

I'm tempted to suspect that these key presses are executed in the App context instead of the Win 10 OS context in which the App is running in. How do we execute Key Presses in the Win 10 Context? I've tried creating a Universal App DLL and importing it to my Universal App, however this was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to synthesize input in a Universal app. The SendInput API (and equivalents) that InputSimulator uses to inject input is available only to classic Win32 desktop apps, not to Windows Runtime apps.

If you're trying to control your own app then you can trigger the underlying commands that the input would provoke rather than simulating the input itself. If you're trying to automate another app then this is not possible from a Windows Runtime app.